# get all unix timestamps in current month and last month

Tags: php, mysql, unix-timestamp

I am making a script in which I require views to displayed in today, yesterday, last month, this month. I was able to get views for today and yesterday using the following code:

```
$hour = 12;

$today_count = strtotime("$hour:00:00");
$yest_count = strtotime('-1 day', $today_count);
```

My timestamp in database is unix timestamp . How can i achieve to get this month and last month views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unix timestamp started on 1 January 1970 and counts the seconds since then. To get the time stamp from 7 days ago you need to know how many seconds that is. eg.

7(days)*24(hours)*60(min)*(60 sec) = 604,800

From there you can subtract that from the current timestamp.

time() - 604,800 = time stamp from 7 days ago.

This method will work for any time in the past up until 1 January 1970. Once that is done you can convert that timestamp into any date formate you need.